# Django List Sending To API

Tags: python, django

We are currently in the process of making a new online store program for our students. The current framework we are using is DJANGO. On one of our views which is called completed checkout, it sends an email to the student's counselor to approve the following purchase. That email we are sending via 3rd party is called Postmark. The reason we decided to go with the third party as opposed to Django is to monitor the tracking of the emails and not have to deal with SMTP issues. The API is a REST API and requires JSON, dictionary, or list to be sent to populate the template. I'm going to show you the postmark template in HTML. The following lines within the template are what the API pushes data to.

```
<td width="60%" class="align-left purchase_item">{{product__name}}</td>
<td width="40%" class="align-right purchase_item">{{product__point_price}}</td>
```

Template

```
 <table class="purchase_content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <th class="purchase_heading">
            <p class="align-left">Description</p>
          </th>
          <th class="purchase_heading">
            <p class="align-right">Amount</p>
          </th>
        </tr>
        {{#each receipt_details}}
        <tr>
          <td width="60%" class="align-left purchase_item">{{product__name}}</td>
          <td width="40%" class="align-right purchase_item">{{product__point_price}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
        <tr>
          <td width="80%" class="purchase_footer" valign="middle">
            <p class="purchase_total purchase_total--label">Total Points</p>
          </td>
          <td width="20%" class="purchase_footer" valign="middle">
            <p class="purchase_total">{{points}}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Now below here is the Completed Checkout View. The issue we are having is on line 240. I will highlight it with <--- . The issue we have since we are sending a list to the API is the description line. "description": receipt_details[0]['product__name']['product__name'] if you write it like this, no issue. However, you have to set an index. I don't want to set an index, I want every item within the list that has the key product__name to be displayed on the receipt, if you specify the index, it will only send that item. So this is the issue I am having in trying to figure this out. It's been over 4 days trying to troubleshoot this and I have to have this working by next week and I'm begging for help. Greatly appreciate it. Here are the docs for the Postmark API template. https://postmarkapp.com/developer/api/templates-api

```
def checkoutcomplete(request):
    customer = request.user
    order = Order.objects.get(customer= customer , complete = False, )
    favorites = Favorite.objects.filter(customer = customer.id)
    today_date = datetime.datetime.today()    
    today_date_strf = datetime.datetime.strftime(today_date,"%m/%d/%Y" )
    items = order.orderitem_set.all() 
    data = items.values("product__name","quanity","product__point_price", "order_id")
    data_list = list(data)
    print(data_list)
   
    try:
        student = Student.objects.get(email = customer.email)
        counselor = User.objects.get(id = student.counselor_id)
        points = K8RunningPoints.objects.filter(student_ps = student.studentpsid).aggregate(Sum("running_total"))['running_total__sum']
        #POST MARK API 
        url = "https://api.postmarkapp.com/email/withTemplate"
        payload = json.dumps({
        "From": "",
        "To": "",
        "TemplateId": 28132290,
        
        "TemplateModel": {
        "counselor_name": "Fellow Counselor",
        "student_name": student.student_name,
        "receipt_id": str(order.transaction_id),
        "date": today_date_strf,
        "points": order.get_cart_total,
        "receipt_details": [
        {
            "product__name": data_list,
            "amount": "amount_Value"
        }
            ]
        },
        "MessageStream": "outbound"
        })
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Postmark-Server-Token': settings.POSTMARK["TOKEN"]
            }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        print(response.text)
        
    except Exception as err1:
        print(err1, "Student user not found.")
        points = 0
        counselor = ""
        student = ""
        #POST MARK API 
        url = "https://api.postmarkapp.com/email/withTemplate"
        payload = json.dumps({
        "From": "",
        "To": "",
        "TemplateId": 28132290,
        
        "TemplateModel": {
        "counselor_name": "Fellow Counselor",
        "student_name": "test-student",
        "receipt_id": str(order.transaction_id),
        "date": today_date_strf,
        "points": order.get_cart_total,
        "receipt_details": [
        {
            "description": receipt_details['product__name'],
            "amount": "amount_Value"
        }
            ]
        },
        "MessageStream": "outbound"
        })
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Postmark-Server-Token': settings.POSTMARK["TOKEN"]
            }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        print(response.text)


    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Response OK, closing order")
        Order.objects.filter(customer= customer , complete = False).update(complete = False)
    else:
        print(response, "Response Error, not closing order")    
   
    return render(request, 'store/checkout_complete.html', {'favorites': favorites,'points': points })
```

Comment: `Order.objects.filter(customer= customer , complete = False).update(complete = False)` typo here? It is no-op.

Comment: Thank you for the catch, for testing I set it to False so the shopping cart order doesn’t go to complete. What I have been doing for testing is processing the order and hitting the back button on browser so I can keep sending receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for clarity and to point out the HtmlBody tag that can be used with the API.  Let me know if you need more code.

The API lets you send an html string as the Html body. That being said, you can can use render_to_string() on your whole html template and send that as the Html Body.  Use a dictionary to fill in the variables in your template, which will allow you to loop through your list of products since it is all being done on your side before sending to the API.  It will be similar to sending an email via Django's mail.send() using any example with a dictionary to fill out the dynamic pieces.

See the example on the right side of the page in this link.
https://postmarkapp.com/developer/user-guide/send-email-with-api/send-a-single-email

now in template, you'll be able to do something like this, then render_to_string():

```
{% for items in receipt_details['product__name'] %}
<tr>
<td width="60%" class="align-left purchase_item">{{items.0}}</td>
<td width="40%" class="align-rightpurchase_item">{{items.2}}</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: also not sure why you are using different key names in your "description" in your "try" versus "except"

Comment: Thank you for the response. The HTML template isn't on DJANGO, it's on the Postmarks website. Using DJANGO template tags won't work.

Comment: It will if you use the render to string method I showed you and the HTMLbody.  The template is rendered on your side then sent over as a string with the HTML already rendered correctly

Comment: It looks like you were able to copy most of the template from the website.  Grab it and put it in a Django template on your side.  The API gives you an option to not use a template I'd